# Why does SVG viewbox attribute only work on inline SVG?

Tags: svg

I downloaded some 16x16 SVG icons that used the viewbox attribute to scale the original code to fit into 16x16 canvas on download. Now what I am experiencing is that I can not insert the SVG from an external file anywhere as the viewbox attribute just isn't working on it. If I place the SVG code inline then it works.

Am I missing something, or is this just how it is?

Here is the code.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN' 'http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd'>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" height="16" viewbox="0 0 48 48" width="16">
  <path clip-rule="evenodd" d="M37,47H11c-2.209,0-4-1.791-4-4V5c0-2.209,1.791-4,4-4h18.973
    c0.002,0,0.005,0,0.007,0h0.02H30c0.32,0,0.593,0.161,0.776,0.395l9.829,9.829C40.84,11.407,41,11.68,41,12l0,0v0.021                                                                                                 
    c0,0.002,0,0.003,0,0.005V43C41,45.209,39.209,47,37,47z M31,4.381V11h6.619L31,4.381z M39,13h-9c-0.553,0-1-0.448-1-1V3H11
    C9.896,3,9,3.896,9,5v38c0,1.104,0.896,2,2,2h26c1.104,0,2-0.896,2-2V13z M33,39H15c-0.553,0-1-0.447-1-1c0-0.552,0.447-1,1-1h18 
    c0.553,0,1,0.448,1,1C34,38.553,33.553,39,33,39z M33,31H15c-0.553,0-1-0.447-1-1c0-0.552,0.447-1,1-1h18c0.553,0,1,0.448,1,1
    C34,30.553,33.553,31,33,31z M33,23H15c-0.553,0-1-0.447-1-1c0-0.552,0.447-1,1-1h18c0.553,0,1,0.448,1,1C34,22.553,33.553,23,33,23  z" 
    fill-rule="evenodd"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: External SVGs have requirements that inline SVGs do not. For example `xmlns` attributes, and browser same-origin restrictions.  Without more info about how you are loading the SVG, and what its contents are, we cannot really help you.

Comment: Note also that the attribute is called viewBox and not viewbox. For inline that distinction does not matter, for standalone it does.

Comment: I have updated the post and added the code. *update*: I changed the <b>viewbox</b> to <b>viewBox</b> like Robert suggested and now it works if i embed the external file. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Note that it's `viewBox` not `viewbox` - the browser might save you sometimes, but not always.

See the following for full details:
https://jsfiddle.net/t88pLgbb/4/

Comment: You should add code snippets to your answer as well :)